# How much disk does Windows use?

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualbox

I am a happy Linux user, but Skype for Linux is too buggy (sometimes the microphone in Skype does not work).

I need to install Windows in VirtualBox in order to use Windows Skype.

Currently the **only** reason I need Windows is for Skype. But I may probably need some other Windows software in the future. (However I remind that I am a happy Linux user.)

1. Which version of Windows to use? (My boss says Windows 10, but I want to hear different opinions.)
2. What is the recommended size of the disk in VirtualBox?

I have 8GB RAM (DDR3-1333). (I was donated today 4GB DDR3 and 460GB HDD so that my Linux performance would not be reduced by constantly running Windows in VirtualBox.)

Comment: Do you have specific requirements for other versions of Windows? If not use Windows 10. If you look at the [official](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications) documentation you should get an idea of the requirements. I'd probably go for 40-60 GB and 4 GB RAM. As you need to encode video you might run into issues with graphics acceleration.

Comment: The specific requirement is to be able to run Skype. Isn't this requirement clear from my question? And no, we do not use video in Skype

Comment: VirtualBox will by default set up a dynamic HDD which only takes as much space as data inside VM actually occupies. You can safely create a "larger" virtual disk and just use it less space. Resizing small VHDs is a bit of a pain.

Comment: "But I may probably need some other Windows software in the future." as you seem to lack any further requirements also read the [Skype requirements](https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-windows/system-requirements/).

Comment: Keep in mind that you need to make audio work. You should evaluate first. There is absolutely no way to tell if your plan is feasible.

Comment: There are 3 Skype versions available on Linux: the latest official release (Skype 4), the latest beta release (Skype 5) and the [Web App](https://web.skype.com/). It may be worth investigating one of the Linux alternatives before trying a VM solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which version of Windows to use?

You should use the version of Windows which satisfy the requirements of your project.

> What is the recommended size of the disk in VirtualBox?

The system requirements for Windows 10 is as follows.

> [image]

The system requirements for Windows 8.1 is as follows.

> [image]

The system requirements for Windows 7 is as follows.

> [image]

## Sources

- Source: [Windows 10 Specifications & Systems Requirements](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications)
- Source: [Windows 8 Specifications & Systems Requirements](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12660/windows-8-system-requirements)
- Source: [Windows 7 Specifications & Systems Requirements](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10737/windows-7-system-requirements)

Answer (score 1):

I currently run Windows 10 on my personal Windows laptop although if you have the option I would opt for Windows 7. It's much more stable and less of a resource hog. Minimum specs for Windows 10 are as follows.

Processor:
1 gigahertz (GHz) or faster processor or SoC
RAM:
1 gigabyte (GB) for 32-bit or 2 GB for 64-bit
Hard disk space:
16 GB for 32-bit OS 20 GB for 64-bit OS
Graphics card: 
DirectX 9 or later with WDDM 1.0 driver
Display: 
800x600